# Avoid including the current and parent directories

Tags: python, for-loop, directory, parent

So, I'm looping through my files and folders as follows:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(img):
```

How can we avoid including the `current` (**.**) and `parent` (**..**) directories in such search?

Thanks.

Comment: not sure your question is clear enough, the actual entries `.` and `..` do not show up in the os.walk results.

Answer (score 0):

`os.walk()` wouldn't plow through your parent directory (I'm assuming you mean the parent of `img`), so you wouldn't need to worry there.  If you just want to skip the current directory assigned to `img`, it's simple:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(img):
    if root == img: continue
    # your code for the children dirs and files here #
```